# How does one share an existing iOS provisioning profile (or app due for submission)?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, provisioning-profile

A colleague has a completed iPhone app ready for submission to the App Store. In his iTunesConnect/Apple Dev account/XCode/etc. he has his own profiles and certifs all set up. Now we would like to pass responsibility for the submission to me. I have my own iTunesConnect/Apple Dev account/XCode/etc. as you might imagine, associated with my own business.

I'll be making the first submission, but ideally we'd like to both be able to make them for future releases, and I'm imagining it would be best to use his rather my than my Apple Dev account, as otherwise the app will be associated with my company rather than his, and he built the app for his client.

Yes? No? What is the best way ahead please?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: You both need to be members of the same development team.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11. In this context, can I specifically ask what the ambiguous phrase "development team" refers to please?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/17917209/285190

Comment: Are you using automatic code signing?  Or manual code signing where you specify the signing identity, profile, etc.?

Comment: I will use whatever is most suitable @wottle

Comment: Are you referring to this sort of thing @Paulw11?: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html

Comment: Yes, but as hotpaw2 says, if this app is for a client then neither of you should be submitting the app to Apple; the client should have a corporate developer program membership and you should submit the app using that team membership so that the app shows as published by "Acme" or whatever, not either of your individual names

Comment: Yes, thanks @Paulw11, I've been a bit slow today, but I managed to figure for myself after reading that link through, but it's good to get confirmation, so thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are individual Apple Developer enrollments, then there is no team.  You can only have developer teams with corporate/company Apple Developer enrollments/accounts. With individual accounts, only the enrolled agent (using their own developer account login) can download their certificates and provisions and submit apps under their accounts name.

If you do let the other developer use or log into your Mac to make an app submission using their own developer account, you might want to set up a separate User account on your Mac for that purpose, in order not to mix together the keychain certificates and logins of two accounts, which can make a mess.

If you want the app in the App store to be listed under the end clients name (recommended), and that client is a corporation, not an individual, then you might want to get added to the client's (enrolled in Apple's Developer program as a company) team.